# compare maps in different formats - elixir

Tags: elixir

I am using maps in elixir.

some are in `%{"foo": "bar"}` format

and some are in `%{"foo" => "bar"}`

I have two maps:

```
a = %{"foo": "bar"}
b = %{"foo" => "bar"}
```

how can I compare these two maps?

```
Map.equal?(a, b)
```

returns `false`

Comment: maybe this: http://learningwithjb.com/posts/the-many-different-ways-to-key-elixir-maps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maps that you have are not in different formats. They have different keys.

```
iex(1)> Map.equal? %{"foo": 4}, %{:"foo" => 4}
true
```

Using the first (`"foo":`) is just short hand for writing the second (`:"foo" =>`)

The current `Map.equal?/2` function looks to make sure that the keys and values are the same.

In Elixir `:"foo"` is an atom and `"foo"` is a binary (sometimes referred to as a string).

```
iex(1)> is_atom :"foo"
true
iex(2)> is_binary :"foo"
false
iex(3)> is_atom "foo"
false
iex(4)> is_binary "foo"
true
```

This is why `Map.equal?/2` is failing, because these two values are not the same.

However, if you do not care about the types being different and just more care about the "contents" of the type, you could convert all of the keys (and maybe the values) into strings and then compare that.

```
for {key, value} <- my_map do
  {inspect(key), inspect(value)}
end
```

Please note that the code above does not take into consideration nested maps and will just blindly convert it to a string, which may or may not be what you want to do.

Unfortunately, this would mean you would need to traverse both maps multiple times. Once to convert each map, and then again to test if they are equal. This could take a long time if either of the maps are quite big.

Preferably stick to how `Map.equal?/2` works. If the keys are of different types, they should not be equal. Though, if you really need to, you can do the conversion yourself.

Comment: I think is worth stressing is that `:foo == :"foo"`, the quotes are there to handle some non-standard characters.

Comment: Yes. Thank you @nietaki. An example of a non-standard character would be a space. You cannot represent something with a space as an atom without the quotes.